# bind mouse event to javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, mouseevent

Is there any way to bind a mouse event such as 'mouseover' to a JavaScript object?

```
function test(x,y,z){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
   this.add = function(){
       $('body').append("<div id='"+this.z+"'>test: x:"+this.x" y:"+this.y"</div>");
   }
   return this.add();
}

t1 = new test(1,2,3);
t2 = new test(2,3,4);
```

In my code I have a class/objects defined in the following structure, is there any way to attach a event listener to the appended div, but be able to access the object properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, after you added it to the body, so within your `this.add` function you can bind your events:

```
$("#"+this.z).mouseover(function(){
     // Function
});
```

But you know ID's can't start with a number right?

Do this if you want to use `this.z`. I am using `div[0]` because all jQuery objects are Arrays, so the 0th element is the element I just created.

```
function test(x,y,z){
   var div = $("<div id='"+this.z+"'>test: x:"+this.x+" y:"+this.y+"</div>").appendTo("body");
   div[0].y = y;
   div[0].x = x;
   div[0].z = z;
   div.mouseover(function(){
       alert(this.x);
   });

   return div;
}

t1 = new test(1,2,3);
t2 = new test(2,3,4);
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply however i have tryed this and from within this function i.e `$("#"+this.z).mouseover(function(){  alert(this.x) });` i cannot access the properties of the object e.g this.x / this.y 
and about the ID's my bad i was just entering random text.

Comment: That is becaue the `div` you create is the new element, updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid to add elements to the page's DOM through JavaScript using
HTML.

HTML is for **content** as JavaScript is for **behavior**. Important rule
for a good code.

Just create your DIV element (it will be an ordinary object) and do whatever
you want to it, from appending to adding event listeners.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.setAttribute('id', 'foobar');
div.textContent = 'lol';

div.addEventListener('mouseover', myEventCallback, false);

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

By using a decent JavaScript lib, you can reduce the above to two lines
of clean code.